# Can't open the connection after upgrading to SQL Server 2014

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2014, sqlconnection

Recently I have upgraded my SQL Server from 2012 to SQL Server 2014.

Now all my applications connected to this server can't instantiate the connection.

I debug the code and I get the following exception :

> 'Connection.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type
>   System.InvalidOperationException

My connection string like this :

```
 <add name="sql_r" 
      connectionString="Data Source=172.XX.XX.X;Initial Catalog=Attendance;User ID=ll_web;password=XXXXXXXXXXX;" 
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: Did you check the TCP connection in the configuration manager of the SQL Server 2014?

Comment: Can you please check your sql server service is running within services.msc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the code, there are a couple of possible things which could make your `SQL Server Connection` failed from the setup itself. I will try to list 3 which I think might be common:

1. Check your **SQL service**, whether it is running. Check your service by running `"service.msc"` from your `Run` windows. Check for service name `SQL Server (YourInstanceName)` (the default for `YourInstanceName` is `MSSQLSERVER`). Check if it is running. You may also want to check if `SQL Server Browser` is running. Run them.
2. Check you **Firewall**, check if your newly installed SQL Server `paths` are among the allowed `paths`. You could get the `paths` by `[right-clicking - properties -> path to executable]` on the service names of your `SQL Server` in point 1. Include them in your `Firewall` allowed paths.
3. Check your **TCP Port**, Open the `SQL Server 2014 Configuration Manager`, in the `SQL Server Network Connection -> Protocols for [YourInstanceName] -> TCP/IP`. Do `right-click -> properties -> IP Addresses Tab`, check the `TCP Port` for you `IP Addresses`. Typically all is set to `1433`, including the `IPAll`. If this is not the case, set them.